# CSS: Can you achieve column-count with flexboxes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, column-count

I have been trying to achieve CSS `column-count: 3` property by using flex containers

**What I would like to achieve:**

```css
.main {
  column-count: 3;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="category">
    <h1>Category 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Blanditiis maiores minima reiciendis culpa nam, ratione, impedit a non aperiam ad eaque qolli reiciendis culpa nam, ratione, impedit a non aperiam ad eaque qollia.</p>
  </div>
  
    <div class="category">
    <h1>Category 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum reiciendis culpa nam, ratione, impedit a non aperiam ad eaaque quaerat rem ipsum veniam, maxime eligendi debitis odit mollitia.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="category">
    <h1>Category 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum doloitia.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**Where I'm stuck with flex-box**

```css
.main {
      display: flex;
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      background: #eee;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">

      <div class="category">
        <h1>Category 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Blanditiis maiores minima reiciendis culpa nam, ratione, impedit a non aperiam ad eaque qolli reiciendis culpa nam, ratione, impedit a non aperiam ad eaque qollia.</p>
      </div>
      
        <div class="category">
        <h1>Category 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum reiciendis culpa nam, ratione, impedit a non aperiam ad eaaque quaerat rem ipsum veniam, maxime eligendi debitis odit mollitia.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="category">
        <h1>Category 3</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doloitia.</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

From here, I can't figure out how to move the overflow of *category1* to the second column. Is it achievable with flex?

Comment: Nope, flexbox wouldn't allow that. Flex-children don't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, I'm afraid. :(

Every flex item (direct child of any element with `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` set on it) establishes a new formatting context, meaning that any child of the item will be contained within it. As such, runs of text will always be separated like that when you use flex.

If you'd like to learn more, [here's an introduction to formatting contexts from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Intro_to_formatting_contexts).

Answer (score -1):

Try to romove the height from the css:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
}
```